# Get div content inside (javascript code) using jquery or any way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to get the #email div content insdie my javascript code.

**Example:**

```
<div id="email">useremail@gmail.com</div>
```

I want to print email address here

```
document.write('<img src="' + get_gravatar('Email Here', 150) + '" />');
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [to not use document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802943).

If I understand you, using jquery:

```
(function($) //IIEF format
{
    $(function() //wait for doc ready
    {
        var $img = $('<img></img>'); //create img tag using jquery
        var email = $('#email').text().trim() //could also be .html() to get inner html
        $img.attr('src', get_gravatar(email, 150) ) //add email to src attribute of img tag 
        $('body').append($img); //change 'body' with whatever you want to add it to; this will append the img tag into the document
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Not working :/ , try it please [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=F0O577DN2ZOO)

Comment: When trying to run it, I'm getting an error from inside the get_gravatar function: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0O5N1T083IP

Comment: Omg, it's working fine! , thank you very very much my friend :)

Comment: Cheers. Great to hear. Fixed my answer to wait for the doc ready (which was the only real change I did in the tryit page).

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to get the text and store it in a variable and then you can use that.

You can use the following:

```
var email = document.getElementById('email');
document.write('<img src="' + get_gravatar(email, 150) + '" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerHTML` or `.textContent` in javascript of the div email

> The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML)
>   of an element.

```
var emailId = document.getElementById('email').innerHTML;
document.write('<img src="' + get_gravatar(emailId, 150) + '" />');
```

or

> textContent returns null if the element is a document, a document
>   type, or a notation. To grab all of the text and CDATA data for the
>   whole document, one could use document.documentElement.textContent.

```
var emailId = document.getElementById('email').textContent;
document.write('<img src="' + get_gravatar(emailId, 150) + '" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write('<img src="' + get_gravatar(document.getElementById("email").innerHTML, 150) + '" />');
```

JQuery

```
document.write('<img src="' + get_gravatar($("#email").val(), 150) + '" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps You,

```
var mail = document.getElementById('email').innerHTML;
document.write('<img src="' + get_gravatar(mail, 150) + '" />');
```